# Corrupted string when returning new string from objective-c to swift

Tags: objective-c, string, swift, nsstring, corruption

I try to build a string from an enum in Objective-C:

```
+ (NSString *)getStringFromKey:(ITGenericNotification)key {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"notification%lu", (long)key];
}
```

This code worked really well for over a year

However when I try to call it from swift with:

```
let notificationKey = NSNotification.getStringFromKey(ITNotificationWithObject.DidChangedQuestion.hashValue)
```

I get a corrupted string :[image: corruptedstring]

What is happening ? 
The value of ITGenericNotification seems to be correct,

`ITGenericNotification` is defined as `typedef long ITGenericNotification;` and is used as base type for an enum with `typedef NS_ENUM(ITGenericNotification, ITNotificationWithObject)`

And `+ (NSString *)getStringFromKey:(ITGenericNotification)key` is implemented as a category to `NSNotification`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `.rawValue`, not `.hashValue`, to get the underlying
integer value of the enum.

(Also the debugger variables view is sometimes wrong. When in doubt,
add a `println()` or `NSLog()` to your code to verify the values of
your variables.)

Comment: Indeed, I was mislead by the type displayed in autocompletion.